# Twilio Webchat restart conversation

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to restart the conversation of Twilio Webchat whenever I want. It only restars when is sent to a Flex agent and the agent concludes the conversation. But if the conversation doesnt´t sends to the agent, then there is no way to restart, the conversation always keep running.
I´m doing it by reloading with the 'Clear site data' of the console but not always work.

[image: flow ending without sending to a Flex agent]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, can you explain further with perhaps screenshots? Why would a conversation not go to an agent?

Comment: A conversation may not pass by a a 'send to twilio' widget in the Studio flow, and just send text messages. I have edited with a picture of it.
Now, when the conversation on the webchat reach that final point, there is no way to restart the conversation from the beggining, and I want to know how can I do that.

Comment: Do you have the Flex Janitor enabled for the [web messaging flow](https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/messaging)?